# background image not showing but other styles are showing for the same class or element

Tags: html, css, background-image

Why is the background image not showing, but if I change other properties like color or even background color it works? The image path is correct.
It is like this

```css
.container {
            background-image: url('/myapp/peter-broomfield-m3m-lnR90uM-unsplash.jpg');
            z-index: -1;
            opacity: 1;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
            height: 900px;
            width: 900px;}
```

Comment: try it  `background-image: url(myapp/peter-broomfield-m3m-lnR90uM-unsplash.jpg);`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I'm guessing something is probably wrong with your relative image path.  Double check your directory structure and test the absolute path by entering it in a new browser window to make sure the image is loading.  You can look for a 404 error in the browser console. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovy0264c/) that works fine with your CSS and a placeholder image.

Comment: Try ./ In the path. It's something issue with path.

Comment: by absolute path you meant the direct internet link?

Answer (score 0):

There must to be some problem with the relative path of image you have used.

Comment: bro, I checked the path a lot of times. It is perfect. Also, I used the image without ' '  and again no result.  

Comment: Did you try with the absolute path ? just to be sure that there is no issue accessing that image location from the code.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS syntax is correct. However, the leading forward slash of your relative path plays an important role.

`/myapp/peter-broomfield-m3m-lnR90uM-unsplash.jpg`
This relative path says "go to the root of your website and find the 'myapp' folder from there.

`myapp/peter-broomfield-m3m-lnR90uM-unsplash.jpg`
This one says "look for the 'myapp' folder from where the css file is located.

```css
.container {
            background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492_960_720.jpg');
            z-index: -1;
            background-color: red;
            opacity: 1;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
            height: 900px;
            width: 900px;}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I got the solution. It was because the image only appears when I used the direct source address of it. My problem was that I downloaded it and kept it in the file of my visual studio code and used the image from there. But I don't know why sometimes the downloaded link works and sometimes it do not.